# Open pay link in app instead of web browser

Tags: android-pay

I'm using the Google Wallet API to create virtual cards in Google Wallet.

The API returns to me a token and I create a link like `pay.google.com/gp/v/save/{token}`

After that, I'm doing this in js to automatically open the link:

```
let a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = link;
a.click();
a.remove();
```

But, this open Google Wallet in the user's web browser. I would like to open it in the Google Wallet android app.

How i can achieve this?